# What's the actual behavior of expr.replace() when using "exact=False"

Tags: replace, sympy

I've been studying SymPy doc's. I found the following at the Topics->Basics->Core->Basic section:

```
>>> e = x**(1 + y)
>>> (x**(1 + y)).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a, exact=False)
x
>>> (x**(1 + y)).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a, exact=True)
x**(-x - y + 1)
>>> (x**y).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a, exact=False)
x
>>> (x**y).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a, exact=True)
x**(1 - y)
```

This behavior doesn't seem coherent with the rest of the documentation of expr.replace(). Can some heroe please elaborate regarding these outputs?

I'd expect the first output, for example, to be: x**(-y)

Here is the [link](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace) to the place in the documentation where the previous example appears. It is right after section 3.1, when introducing "exact=False"

Comment: Please show complete code and include a link to the docs that you refer to.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace under 3.1.

Comment: The code is still incomplete. How did you define x, y, a? What modules did you import?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin The whole thing is in the link. I'm just pasting part of the documentation which I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

### Short version

The example uses an unconstrained `Wild` (`a`), which should normally be given `exclude` or `properties` arguments to make more sensible matches, while their use of `exact` is largely a red herring

```py
>>> a = Wild('a', properties=[lambda a: a.is_Symbol])  # constraint
>>> (x**(1 + y)).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a)
x**(-y)
```

---

### Extended Version

From earlier blocks in the [`.replace` method examples you're referring to](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace), `a` is a `Wild` (**2.1 pattern -> expr**) and `x` and `y` are basic Symbols (**Initial setup**)

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y   # initial setup
>>> a, b = map(Wild, 'ab')       # 2.1
>>> srepr((a, b, x, y))
"(Wild('a'), Wild('b'), Symbol('x'), Symbol('y'))"
```

The docs say about the `exact` argument

> Setting this to `False` accepts a match of `0`; while setting it `True` accepts all matches that have a `0` in them.

More clearly, `exact=True` prevents `0` from matching `Wild`

```py
>>> sympify(0).replace(Wild('w'), 5, exact=False)
5
>>> sympify(0).replace(Wild('w'), 5, exact=True)
0
>>> f(0).replace(f(a), lambda a: f(a + 1), exact=False)
f(1)
>>> f(0).replace(f(a), lambda a: f(a + 1), exact=True)
f(0)
```

*However*, replacement in the given example (and in general) becomes confusing because SymPy can make bizarre-looking matches like replacing simply `1` as `x**(1+a)`, effectively breaking apart the expression

```py
>>> sympify(1).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a)      # a: -1 -> x**1
x
>>> x.replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a, exact=False)  # a:  0 -> x**-0
1
>>> x.replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a, exact=True)   # doesn't match
x
```

You can add the `map=True` arg to see the result mapping (tuple of `(result, match_dict)` is returned), highlighting the unexpected `1:x` mapping

```py
>>> (x**(1 + y)).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a, map=True, exact=False)[1]
{x: 1, 1: x}
>>> (x**(1 + y)).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a, map=True, exact=True)[1]
{1: x, x**(x + y): x**(-x - y + 1)}
```

What's really happening here is that the docs and example imo don't make it suffiently clear that they expect someone to be familar with `Wild` when using it, and go right into showing off some of the bizarre matches possible .. while the docs for `Wild` right away suggest using its `exclude` and `properties` to constrain matches
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.symbol.Wild

Also note that for a pattern like **2.2. pattern -> func**, only the wild value is passed to the lambda, which the examples further mask by having the same form as the original equation

```py
obj.replace(pattern(wild), lambda wild: expr(wild))
```

For example, we could provide a property that `a` can't be `-1`

```py
>>> sympify(1).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a)  # a: -1 -> x**1
x
>>> sympify(1).replace(x**(a - 5), lambda a: a)      # a:  5
5
>>> a = Wild('a', properties=[lambda a: a!=-1])      # don't match -1
>>> sympify(1).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a)  # doesn't match
1
```

Fundamentally `.replace()` or `.match()` with an unrestricted `Wild` is setting oneself up for failure and the inclusion of `exact` only serves to handle a special case amongst many unexpected matches

---

To complete the example, we can then try to interpret what might have been wanted by someone using the example

Perhaps finding exactly `y` as the match? (same as my first example)

```py
>>> a = Wild('a', properties=[lambda a: a.is_Symbol])  # constraint
>>> (x**(1 + y)).replace(x**(1 + a), lambda a: x**-a)
x**(-y)
```

Or inverting the power

```py
>>> (x**(1 + y))**-1                               # trivial
x**(-y - 1)
>>> (x**(1 + y)).replace(Pow, lambda a, b: a**-b)  # match, unpack Pow
x**(-y - 1)
```